# Bulk Create folders in document library using client object model

Tags: document-library, client-object-model, folder, bulk

I want to create folder on SharePoint document library using client object model (C#). Below is the code which does that.

```
ContentTypeCollection listContentTypes = list.ContentTypes;
 clientContext.Load(listContentTypes, types => types.Include
                                     (type => type.Id, type => type.Name,
                                     type => type.Parent));

 var result = clientContext.LoadQuery(listContentTypes.Where(c => c.Name == "Folder"));

clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

ContentType folderContentType = result.FirstOrDefault();

ListItemCreationInformation newItemInfo = new ListItemCreationInformation();
newItemInfo.UnderlyingObjectType = FileSystemObjectType.Folder;
newItemInfo.LeafName = Foldername;
ListItem newListItem = list.AddItem(newItemInfo);

newListItem["ContentTypeId"] = folderContentType.Id.ToString();
newListItem["Title"] = Foldername;
ewListItem.Update();

clientContext.Load(list);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

I need to create thousands of folders and am looking for a method that supports bulk operations, resulting in a single server call. Current method is time consuming as each request to create a folder is done individually.